# What does the % in a print between the format and variables actually do?

Tags: python

I'm just starting to fool around with formatting the output of a print statement.

The examples I've seen have a % after the format list and before the arguments, like this:

```
>>> a=123
>>> print "%d" % a
123
```

What is the meaning of the `%` and more important, why is it necessary?

Answer (score 7):

It's the [string formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html), it tells Python to look at the string to the left, and build a new string where %-sequences in the string are replaced with formatted versions of the values from the right-hand side of the operator.

It's not "necessary", you can print values directly:

```
>>> print a
123
```

But it's nice to have `printf()`-style formatting available, and this is how you do it in Python.

As pointed out in a comment, note that the string formatting operator is not connected to `print` in any way, it's an operator just like any other. You can format a value into a string without printing it:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> padded = "%05d" % a
>>> padded
00123
```

Comment: And it has absolutely nothing to do with `print`. It all happens before the `print` is even considered.

Comment: slick!  this forum is clearly a great source for useful python help.  as we all know there are a lot of places you can go for internet help, but not all are all that helpful ;). thanks to all for being tolerant of some of the real basic questions I've been asking.

Answer (score 4):

In python the `%` operator is implemented by calling the method `__mod__` on the left hand argument, falling back to `__rmod__` on the right argument if it's not found. So what you have written is equivalent to

```
a = 123
print "%d".__mod__(a)
```

Python's string classes simply implement `__mod__` to do string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that this style of string formatting is referred to in the documentation as "old string formatting"; moving forward we should move to the new-style string formatting as described here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

like:

```
>>> a=123
>>> print "{0}".format(a)
123
```

> See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for a description of the various
>   formatting options that can be specified in format strings.
>
> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3.0,
>   and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String
>   Formatting Operations in new code.

Comment: It is not deprecated - it's not marked as such and there are no plans to remove it.

Comment: It's not actually marked as deprecated, but the docs say "because this old style of formatting will eventually be removed from the language, str.format() should generally be used." (see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) I'll edit to reflect -- thanks.

Comment: @bgporter: Speaking of outdated techniques, shouldn't we be calling 'print' as a function instead of a statement?  ;-)    i.e. print("{0}".format(a))